# Unmarshall SOAP fault JAXB

Tags: spring, jaxb, spring-integration

I need help to unmarshall SOAP response using JAXB java class

```
 <soapenv:Fault>
      <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
      <faultstring>DLResponseException</faultstring>
      <detail>...
     ....
```

I created a java class with root element as below

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Fault", namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
public class MFaultResponse{
..
}
```

**Usage:**

```
 InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(sample.getBytes());

    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MFaultResponse.class);  
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();  

    MFaultResponse response= (MFaultResponse) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(is);
    System.out.println(response.getFaultCode());
```

**Exception:**

Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 16; The prefix "soapenv" for element "soapenv:Fault" is not bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not related to Spring Integration, neither to Spring at all.

This is typical JAXB situation, when you have an xml fragment. I understand that this a body of the SOAP response, but as you see the real namespace for that `soapenv` is declared on the root of the SOAP envelope.

If you wouldn't have that prefix you'd be OK to unmarshal the doc, but since it is about a fragment, but not the whole SOAP response, I'd suggest to do manual XPath to extract those 3 tags' values and build such a `MFaultResponse` manually.

Not sure though, why the standard `SoapFault` approach in Spring WS doesn't work for you..

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I printed output again and it is coming with schema also <soapenv:Fault xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">. So updated code with @XmlRootElement(name="Fault", namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/") and it works.

Comment: Well, good to hear, but I still believe that my answer is relevant and can be accepted